# Fluidsynth vs. TiMidity 2.13 -- why does the former play beautiful cymbals and the latter play trashy ones?

Tags: midi

Previously I had been using VLC fluidSynth to export my midis to other formats, until recently when I discovered that it was ever-so-slightly out of tune and TiMidity actually played my songs without clipping. That was a major plus.

However, there was one thing that fluidSynth did absolutely awesomely, and that was play percussion. Every time it played cymbals they must have lasted at least one and a half seconds, and they sounded great.

But when I play the same midi in TiMidity with the same soundfont, it always cuts off the cymbals, playing them for maybe half a second. I even tried assigning all the drums to a different soundfont but they still got cut off.

Is there any way I can get TiMidity to stop doing this? I know I could export the drums from VLC and the melody from TiMidity and put them together in Audacity, but that's kind of a pain, especially when TiMidity should seemingly be able to play cymbals right itself.

Comment: timidity 2.13 is not the latest version. Perhaps the latest 2.14 version (available at its sourceforge site) will work better? Another idea is to edit timidity.cfg - the manpage for it says some percussion instruments can benefit from the 'keep' option.

Comment: I was able to compile that and get it working just long enough to confirm that it didn't fix the percussion problem. After that I spent hours and hours and hours trying to get all the features I had on the 2.13 binary compiled back in, but I kept getting the same strange error about expecting MidiEncodermetadatacallbacksomething and getting SeekableMidiEncoder instead, and just gave up because there was no information about it on the internet and I'd tried ~7 different versions of flac already. So, I can't upgrade to 2.14, because I somewhat need flac export and 2.14 just can't have it.

Answer (score 4):

Timidity++ comes with some questionable default settings that essentially ignore the effects specified by the soundfont and midi source in favour of global defaults.

Though I have no insight into why the developers have chosen to do that, I can speculate that it is because it's a lot easier to find awful midi files made by people who don't understand midi or music very well, or cobbled together soundfonts or patchsets that make perfect midi sound like a high-school band practising for the first time.

Try the following settings in your timidity.cfg, they tell timidity to respect
the wishes of the creators of the soundfont and midi source.

```
# Enable all midi effects
opt -Ewpvsetoz

# Don't cut sustain to save CPU 
opt --no-fast-decay

# Pan quickly, even if it sounds bad
opt --fast-panning

# Set chorus and reverb by song & soundfont
opt EFreverb=1
opt EFchorus=1

# Never kill voices to save CPU
opt -k0

# Sustain fades after three seconds (3000ms)
opt -m3000
```

You may feel timidity sounds worse with these settings, if that's the case it probably means you're using a crappy soundfont. The FluidR3 soundfonts are okay for most midi files if you just want to get up and running quickly, however I recommend the Tyroland soundfont, it has well matched and balanced instruments with proper settings for reverb and chorus and sounds great with fluidsynth and timidity.

https://musical-artifacts.com/artifacts/1305

If it still sounds bad, try finding better midi files or playing better.

Comment: Not sure about OP, but this improved Timidity's output for me by a lot! Thanks!